# Auto alignment of dynamic width inline elements with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

Is there a way, using flexbox, to align items that are dynamic in width neatly?

E.g.

```
---------------------------------
| textlink1 textlink2 textlink3 |
| sometext  sometext2 sometext3 |
```

rather than

```
---------------------------------
| textlink1 textlink2 textlink3 |
| sometext sometext2 sometext3  |
```

I’ve got a menu list that’s `flex-direction: column` but for responsiveness, I’d want to use row and have it dynamically align the inline items neatly.

```css
div {
  width: 250px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: solid 1px #000;
}

a {
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">textlink1</a>
  <a href="#">textlink2</a>
  <a href="#">textlink3</a>
  <a href="#">sometext1</a>
  <a href="#">sometext2</a>
  <a href="#">sometext3</a>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jhntqLjq/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `flex-basis: 33.3333%` to define a initial length of the flex-item

***Stack Snippet***

```css
div {
  width: 250px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: solid 1px #000;
}

a {
  flex-basis: 33.3333%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">textlink1</a>
  <a href="#">textlink2</a>
  <a href="#">textlink3</a>
  <a href="#">sometext1</a>
  <a href="#">sometext2</a>
  <a href="#">sometext3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: @totalnoob well in this case you will need to use `flex-basis: 33.33%;` to define a initial length of the flex-item https://jsfiddle.net/jhntqLjq/12/